# catching wrong path in JUnit

Tags: junit, junit4

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;



    ChartIO io = new ChartIO();
    @Test 
    public void test_readFile_SadPath() {
        String path="abc.txt";
        try {
            io.readFile(path);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            assertTrue(ex instanceof FileNotFoundException );
        }
    }
```

I want to create a test case for below code but it gives always this error

cannot find symbol

[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertTrue(boolean)

[ERROR]   location: class demo.junit_class_demo.grades.ChartIOTest

```
 public int[] readFile(String filepath) {
    List<Integer> linesList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            linesList.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File " + filepath + " does not exist");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }

    int[] linesArray = new int[linesList.size()];
    for (int index = 0; index < linesList.size(); index++) {
        linesArray[index] = linesList.get(index);
    }

    return linesArray;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Whole error lines:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/X/Desktop/Y/Z/A/project/unit_test_demo/src/test/java/grades/ChartIOTest.java:[22,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method assertTrue(boolean)
  location: class demo.junit_class_demo.grades.ChartIOTest
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.787 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-16T18:04:35+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project 481.demo.child: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/Z/Desktop/X/Y/K/project/unit_test_demo/src/test/java/grades/ChartIOTest.java:[22,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertTrue(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: class demo.junit_class_demo.grades.ChartIOTest
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is whole error lines.

Comment: Did you import `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue()` method

Comment: Yes, i did. Also i added the import lines in code now.@MensurQulami

Comment: Can you share the complete exception stack trace?

Comment: i added.@MensurQulami

Comment: Btw. i solved. It depends on static call so i must call it with Assert.assertTrue(...); . Thanks for attention.@MensurQulami

Comment: So, basically what I said in the first comment was correct :D. I assumed you already know that it is a static import. IDEs usually do that import automatically.